# Setting DataContext to current class results in an infinite loop

Tags: xaml

I am trying to set the DataContext property of a Page to the current class (not caring about the MVC concepts for now).

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <local:MyPage />
</Page.DataContext>
```

Now, I am getting trapped in an infinite loop. I know the reason, it is because I am initializing another object of MyPage class, from an object of MyPage class itself, which creates an infinite loop.

I can solve it by moving the part of the code which needs to be observed by the Views, in a class, say, Models (and then setting the DataContext property to that class). But, isn't there a way to reference the current class (without creating another instance) in XAML? Something like:

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <local:this />
</Page.DataContext>
```

Comment: You could do this in the constructor (in the code behind)

Comment: I got it anyway....You can do it by <Page.DataContext><Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" /></Page.DataContext>...Thanks anyways :)

Comment: I've already included that in my answer below (a few minutes from my comment) ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"` In xaml
- `this.DataContext = this;` in code behind

Answer (score 1):

```
<Page DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">

    ...

</Page>
```